# Change number of products displayed per page (for search results)

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I used the following snippet to change the amount of products displayed on my product-archive pages.

```
add_filter( 'loop_shop_per_page', create_function( '$cols', 'return 18;' ), 18 );
```

But my search results page is only displaying 10 results per page.
Anyone know how to change that so that the results as displays 18 results per page?

Site: http://pmfootwear.com/?s=Imac&post_type=product

Thanks
Joe

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your admin panel, go to Settings -> Reading .  Change the settings "**Blog pages show at most**" to the value as you like. by default it is 10. That's why you are getting 10 results.  Follow the screenshot.

[image]